# how could webAppAccess.getModelName() data is passed to the any static block in linked java object class?

Tags: java, portlet, portal, websphere-portal

i want to access the data inside the static block present in the java class. In below data it could be accessed after the instance of the static block is loaded.

public final static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(OuterClass.class.getName());

```
static String userId= "";
public static void getModelName(WebAppAccess webAppAccess) {
    userId = webAppAccess.getModelName();
    logger.info("USERID   "   + userId);
}
```

static 
    {

```
    String PROPERTIES_FILE = "/config/log4j.properties";
    logger.info("USERID 2   "   + userId);
    if(userId.equals("qwe"))
    System.setProperty("balancer.log", "C:\\log_f.out"); 
    else
        System.setProperty("balancer.log", "C:\\log_f2.out");
    File file = new File ( BSConfig.getHomedir() + PROPERTIES_FILE );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan if static initialization myself as it makes things harder to debug and/or handle issues/exceptions if something goes wrong in that particular code.

Beyond that, there are a couple of issues with the above code:

- WebAppAccess is a user's request-time access to information about the
  request, not just the webapp and it's passed implicitly from actions
  and webAppAccess.callMethod, not on instantiation of the object.
- getModelName() returns the name of the model used to generate the WebApp, it is not the userId  (see webAppAccess.getUserInfo().getUserID() for that ).
- You shouldn't be setting a System (JVM) wide property from a user's instance of a webapp as it would affect all other user requests in that JVM.

In terms of how to handle code that should be initialized once with an LJO, and customizing that initialization from a WEF based model, take a look at the "Initialization method" input in the Advanced section of the Linked Java Object builder.

I hope that info helps,
..Mike Burati 
The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM.